# if condition inside for loop with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which will :
1.Count no. of lines in csv files and pass the count to a for loop

```
@echo It will count no.of lines in file and pass the count 2for loop

P:
cd Exa-WM-Automation\Google-Adword-Task\extra-columns-deleted-so-only-keywords-csv-file
set file=P:\Exa-WM-Automation\Google-Adword-Task\adwords-filename.csv
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo %file% has %cnt% lines
```

2.Then for loop is called which will call a macro script `loop-google-ad-word.iim` at each execution

```
timeout /t 5

    @echo Loop starts now

    for /L %%A in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
        @echo imacro loop is called
        c:
        start /B "" "C:\Users\webmagnet\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="loop-google-ad-word.iim"
    )
```

Now what i require is:

Say cnt = 570 then,

1.After every 30 executions it should run a macro script `logout.iim` & `login.iim`.
2.And then continue the for loop.

So basically an if condition inside for loop which will check if count is multiple of 30 then execute `logout.iim` & `login.iim` else nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delayed expansion for this, i.e. put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the start of your batch file.

Then you can create a new variable in your loop:

```
set /a mod=%%A %% 30
```

and check it for being 0:

```
if !mod!==0 (
  rem do something
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```dos
rem Clear previous logout points
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set logout[') do set "%%A="

rem Calculate new logout points
set "logoutEach=30"
for /l %%A in (%logoutEach%,%logoutEach%,%cnt%) do set "logout[%%A]=1"

for /L %%A in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    if defined logout[%%A] (
        rem Execute logout code
    )
    ....
)
```

This will define a variable for each point where the logout must be done. During the iterations, a test for existence of the variable asociated to the current loop is made: if the variable exists, it is time to logout.